# How to do linear git flow?

Tags: git

My dev shop has a preferred git flow like so:

1. Checkout an issue branch (`issue9`).
2. Solve issue (`serve over port 80`).
3. Commit (`git commit` ...).
4. Merge the issue branch into a local feature branch (`cal`).
5. Push the local feature branch to `origin`.

   - All merges should be fast-forward if at all possible.

This last constraint is making me tear my hair out--in practice, I can either:

1. Merge the issue commit into local feature branch.
2. Whereupon git refuses to push to origin, due to remote changes.
3. Pull remote changes to local feature branch.
4. Git automatically generates a separate merge commit.

OR

1. Pull remote changes to local feature branch.
2. Git automatically generates a separate merge commit.

Is there a setting I can tweak in global/local git config to achieve this behavior? When I try to do this, I end up messing up git and having to run four of five git commands to clean it up.

I just want to `emacs && git commit && git checkout cal && git merge issue9 && git push origin cal`, ya know?

Comment: Have you head of `git-rebase`? Sounds like it's exactly what you're looking for. Or does your company not allow rebasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one-off pulls, you can use `git pull --rebase`:

```
$ git commit
$ git checkout cal
$ git merge issue9
$ git pull --rebase
$ git push origin cal
```

To configure git to always behave this way on `git pull`, make your `~/.gitconfig` look like this:

```
[push]
    default = matching
[branch]
    autosetuprebase = always
[color]
    status = auto
[merge]
    ff = true
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad the only change to my current git flow is just the `--rebase` option to `git pull`.